# An urn contains 2 orange and 2 blue balls and two balls are drawn without replacement.

Tags: probability

Below is a question from my book. I am trying to figure out the following:

a) Is there a method to solve it by just using the definition of conditional probability and no counting techniques?

b) What is the shortest way to solve this problem using any (first semester probability) tools?

> An urn contains four colored balls: two orange and two blue. Two balls are selected at random without replacement, and you are told that at least one of them is orange. What is the probability that the other ball is also orange?

**My Solution:**

Let $A =$ "at least one of the balls is orange" and $B = $ "Both balls are orange". We are trying to find $$ \displaystyle P(B|A) = \dfrac {P(B \cap A)}{P(A)} = \dfrac {P(B)}{P(A)} = \dfrac {\frac {1}{4 \choose 2}}{1-\frac{1}{4 \choose 2}} = \dfrac 15$$

Comment: Doesn't look right. Look at outcomes. O, B; O,O; B, B and B, O. Given orange the other is orange should be 1/3.

Comment: @sku $\dfrac 15$ is also given in the back of the book. I think the elements in your sample space don't have equal probability. If we let $O_1, O_2$ and $B_1, B_2$ be the orange and blue balls, the sample space is $O_1O_2, O_1B_1, O_1B_2, O_2O_1, O_2B_1, O_2B_2, B_1B_2, B_1O_1, B_1O_2, B_2B_1, B_2O_1, B_2O_2$. There are $10$ outcomes with at least one orange ball, and there are $2$ outcomes with two orange balls, so the probability is $\dfrac {2}{10} = \dfrac 15$.

Comment: So the orange balls are not identical. Neither are blue balls, a condition not specified

Comment: @sku I copied the problem exactly as it appears in the book. I don't think it matters if the balls are identical or not, does it?

Comment: I think yes. Remove the indices in your comment. What do you get

Comment: @sku Let's say I have 2 indistuinguishable orange balls and 2 indistinguishable, and I run this experiment in real life and I get a result. I don't think this result would change if I put a black dot on an orange ball and on a white ball so that now I can distinguish them. Removing the indices gets O, B; O,O; B, B and B, O like you said, but I think the outcomes in this sample space are not equally likely.

Comment: Distinguishability matters. Why not consider orange and blue as same?

Comment: @sku I think the answer is that with respect to this experiment, distinguishiblity between orange and blue matters, but distinguishibility between the 2 orange and the 2 blue balls doesn't matter. From the eyes of the experiment, orange ball is orange ball. It doesn't matter if one orange ball has additional features which distinguish it from the other orange ball.

Comment: @sku, When dealing with probability measures involving selecting coloured balls, they are always discrete physical objects whether an observer can distinguish individuals of the same color or not.  The fact that you cannot tell which orange ball is which, does not make them the same orange ball.  (Consider selected one ball from a bag containing 200 orange balls and one blue ball.  Is the probability for selecting an orange ball $1/2$ because there are only two outcomes, or $200/201$ because there are more orange balls than blue?)

Comment: Makes sense. Wasn't thinking too clearly. P(o,o) = 2/4*1/3 = 1/6. P(o,b) = 2/4*2/3 = 1/3 = P(b,o). P(b,b) = 1/6. So answer = $\frac{1/6}{1/6 +1/3 + 1/3} = 1/5$

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is quite okay.   You have correctly applied the definition of conditional probability, and evaluated the probabilities for the events by unwittingly using the fact that the count of orange balls selected follows a *hypergeometric distribution*.

So, indeed the probability for selecting $k$ from two orange balls, and $2-k$ from the two non-orange balls, when selecting two from all four balls without bais or replacement is: $$\mathsf P(X=k)~=~\binom 2k\binom 2{2-k}\div \binom 4 2$$

Thusly:

$$\mathsf P(X=2\mid X\geq 1) ~{= \dfrac{\mathsf P(X=2)}{1-\mathsf P(X = 0)} \\= \dfrac{\big(\binom{2}{2}\binom{2}{0}\big)\div\binom{4}{2}}{\big(\binom{4}{2}-\binom{2}{0}\binom{2}{2}\big)\div\binom{4}{2}} \\= \dfrac{1}{6-1}}$$

Alt.

$$\mathsf P(X=2\mid X\geq 1) ~{= \dfrac{\mathsf P(X=2)}{\mathsf P(X = 1\cup X=2)} \\= \dfrac{\big(\binom{2}{2}\binom{2}{0}\big)\div\binom{4}{2}}{\big(\binom{2}{1}\binom{2}{1}+\binom{2}{2}\binom{2}{0}\big)\div\binom{4}{2}} \\= \dfrac{1}{4+1}}$$